# How to use phpMyAdmin in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin on ubuntu with other LAMP components , but I don't know how to use it .!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you installed it, you may or may not have to create a link to it in your /var/www directory

So open a terminal

```
cd /var/www
ls
```

if you see anything that says phpmyadmin, phpma, or similar just open a browser, and enter **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** into the address bar.

If /var/www doesn't contain a link to phpmyadmin, you'll have to create one.

```
su
cd /var/www
ln -s /where/did/you/install/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

Then youll be able to find it in the browser by going to localhost.

Comment: I have a folder that represnets a database (table, ...) where I have to add this folder to open it using ohomyadmin ?

Comment: good question! personally I would create a new database using phpmyadmin, use a weird name like 456ERT. Then in a terminal; su to root, cd to /, then run a quick **find | grep "456ERT"**